# Enable Unauthenticated binds in OpenLDAP

Tags: ubuntu, openldap

Just want to know if it is possible to configure OpenLDAP to enable unauthenticated binds. That is, the user just types in username and null password, and bind succeeds. There are some products, which are tied to LDAP server (for user name queries), but actually are not interested in authenticating to them

I am trying to configure OpenLDAP on the latest Ubuntu 17.10 machine (the one which does not have slapd.conf, but has cn=config.ldif way of configuring the same)

Comment: What you're really looking for is how to enable anonymous *searches,* and it is all documented. Off topic.

Answer (score 0):

probably what you are looking for are anonymous searches. With this option, you can search users without binding.

Firstly try if you can do an anonymous search typing this in console:

*ldapsearch -x -H ldap://localhost -b dc=example,dc=com*

If you receive results, congratulations, you have the anonymous searches enabled. If don't (probably you will see "Insufficient access"), anonymous searches are not enabled.

Someone did a similar question here: https://serverfault.com/questions/748758/enable-anonymous-bind-in-openldap/748904#748904

Answer (score 0):

Per https://www.openldap.org/doc/admin24/security.html, section 14.3.1, one enters `allow bind_anon_cred` in slapd.conf.  It doesn't say about exactly where that should be listed, so I'm guessing it's a global directive.